# Why does my Neon Text light look like stick with underglow after the render?

Tags: rendering

After I render my simple animation, it looked like this. What could be the problem?[![This is a picture of my rendered animation][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/khJ58.jpg![This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khJ58.jpg!%5BThis) a rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0XqM.jpg)This is the viewport image

Comment: I rendered using eevee.

Comment: Please upload a blend file. Also, what do you want it to look like? it's probably a material issue

Comment: did you check for hidden lights?

Comment: Its supposedly to look like the second image.